# Wolframscript kernel in Visual Studio Code

Tags: scripting, free-wolfram-engine

I installed the free Wolfram Script and Wolfram Engine on my Mac (I do not have Mathematica), and I generated free activation keys. After entering these keys into the terminal, I am able to run `wolframscript` from the terminal successfully. E.g. with a file `filename.wls` with contents `Print["Hello world"];`, I can run `wolframscript -f filename.wls` and everything runs smoothly. Wolframscript is located at `/Application/WolframScript.app/Contents/MacOS/wolframscript`.

In visual studio code, I installed the [Wolfram Language extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WolframResearch.wolfram). Syntax coloring works well, but other things do not (e.g. documentation on hover). Most importantly though, I cannot get the kernel to work. In the `settings.json` file, I added `"wolfram.kernel": "/Applications/WolframScript.app/Contents/MacOS/wolframscript"`. Now, when I open `.wls` files in Visual Studio Code, I get the following error five times:

> Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
>
> The Wolfram Engine could not be activated using your Wolfram ID.
>
> This may have occurred because WolframScript has already activated a different installation of the Wolfram Engine using your account's limited free activation keys. Only two keys are generated when you create a free Wolfram Engine license using https://www.wolfram.com/engine/free-license/.
>
> For additional Wolfram Engine keys, contact Wolfram Research at https://www.wolfram.com/contact-us/.

I also tried changing `"wolfram.kernel"` to `"/Applications/Wolfram Engine.app/Contents/MacOS/WolframKernel"` and `"/Applications/Wolfram Engine.app/Contents/MacOS/Wolfram Engine"`. Both give the same error.

Why does everything work in my terminal but not in Visual Studio Code? How can I get all the features of the Wolfram Language vscode extension to work? Thanks!

Comment: Did you check how many wolfram kernels are running? Maybe another process is already using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling everything and changing "wolfram.kernel" to "/Applications/Wolfram Engine.app/Contents/MacOS/WolframKernel" fixed the problem.